# In pytorch, what situations the loss function need to inherit nn.module?

Tags: pytorch, loss

I am confused about the loss function in PyTorch. Some people define the loss function as a normal python function while others define the loss function by defining a class that inherits nn.Module. So I want to know what situations we need to define the loss function by inheriting nn.Module? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, inheritance from `nn.Module` is only necessary when you want to have trainable variables in this module, otherwise it's optional to inherit it.

So same applies to loss functions, if it contains no such variables (which I assume is the major case), no inheritance is needed.

Comment: For all I know, the "trainable variable" should be defined in the model. Thus, I am confused about the "trainable variable" in the loss function.  Could you further explain the "trainable variable" in the module of the loss function? If possible, could you give me an example? Thank you very much!

Comment: right this is exactly what I mean, so usually for the loss function, there is no such variable, i.e. it only depends on the <pred, label> pairs. So if it does not contain these variables, it won't be necessary to inherit the nn.module